# Javascript Scope in variables and functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I was given this snippet to debug in one of my interviews.

```js
var module = (function sumModule(){
  
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  
  const init = (a,b) =>{
    a = a;
    b = b;
  }
  
  function sum() {
    return a+b;
  }
  
  return {
  sum: sum,
  init
  }
  
})();

module.init(1,2);
console.log(module.sum())
```

The value being returned is 0 (0+0), the assignment of a and b in `func init` didn't overwrite the global `var a` and `var b`. Why is this so, can someone please explain?

NOTE: I was told to fix it without renaming the function parameters `(a,b)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `a` and `b` in the assignments of `init()` function refers to its parameters, not the outer `a` and `b`.
So those assignments don't affect values of the outer `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of renaming the parameters you can also refer to the global variables via their *namespace* like you do with the `init` function.

*Or just rename the global variables, if that is allowed

```js
var module = (function sumModule(){
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  
  const init = (a, b) => {
    module.a = a;
    module.b = b;
  }
  
  function sum() {
    return module.a + module.b;
  }
  
  return {
    sum: sum,
    init,
  }
  
})();

module.init(1, 2);
console.log(module.sum())
```

Comment: This monkey patches just `a` & `b` to the module scope, and does not override the local/private a&b. Put `console.log(module)` before `module.init()` and after you call `.sum` and you see what i mean. a&b are not exisiting on the module object, you monkey patch them after the init call to the object. Private a&b are still 0.

Answer (score 0):

Modified answer from @reyno.
His example just monkey patch `a` & `b` to the `module` object after the `.init` call. Therefore this variables are public and not private anymore.

With this you get the same result, but maintain the variables a & b private.

To achieve this, use a private namespace object, like i did with `private`.

```js
var module = (function sumModule(){

  var private = {
    a: 0,
    b: 0
  }
  
  const init = (a, b) => {
    private.a = a;
    private.b = b;
  }
  
  function sum() {
    return private.a + private.b;
  }
  
  return {
    sum: sum,
    init,
  }
  
})();

console.log(module) // no a or b property
module.init(1, 2);
console.log(module.sum())
console.log(module)  // still no a or b property
```